# iOS App Login Flow

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, authentication

I've developing my first iOS app which allows users to login to an account on our website, and view / add / edit / delete records in a database.

I've written a basic app which handles the process like this;

App starts running.

Each view controller calls a `checkAuth` method from within the `viewWillAppear` method. This method gets the username and password stored within the app, sends them to the server as `GET` variables in a `dataWithContentsOfURL` request. The resulting `JSON` is then checked, if the response is a failure, then an alert dialog is shown, and the user is taken to a different tab (I'm using a tab bar controller) where they are prompted to enter their login details.

Using this method, every time a different view controller takes over (each scene in my storyboard file), the auth method is called. This seems a little wasteful. Is there a better way of ensuring a users login credentials are correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storing the username and password in the app is bad practice.  If modifying the back end is within your control, it would be better to authenticate to the back end, and get back a token that is only good for that device.

From here, you pass the token along with each request, and if the back end determines you have logged out then it should return an error message. This way, the authentication would be checked on an ad-hoc basis and only when sending a request.

I see no reason to do it every time a view loads, unless there is a business requirement for this.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use a "communication management" singleton for this? It would handle all the tasks of authenticating and communicating with the server, and each one of your controllers talks to it without directly interacting with the server.

Comment: Good idea, but still doesn't overcome the issue of "wasted" bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

You could have an inactivity session timeout: via NSTimer.
Set a session timeout marker on successful login (e.g. login time plus 10 minutes).
As the user uses the app keep updating the stored session timeout time to the current time plus 10 minutes (invalidate the timer and create a new one).
When app exits or goes into background invalidate the timer.
Have the timer call a logout method when the timer times out.

Oh, and don't store username/password in the app. Use the keychain to store them encrypted (if necessary to keep them local). I suggest only the username should be stored locally.